# Find Item From an Array Adobe CEP

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe, extendscript

I'm working with adobe CEP 10, I need to get a specific value from an array with the find option in the JSX file. but JSX says find is not a function. how do I get a specific value from an array

Comment: Can you show a sample of your code. It's not clear what do you want to gain. JS has no find function or method for arrays as far as I know. There is a find tool for text string but it's another matter. Basically you need to loop through archive and compare every its element with a sample until you will get what you find. If I understand you right.